# How to Provide a tick symbol in the "dropdown select box" field on selecting the dropdown values using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code.

```
<td>
    <select multiple="multiple" placeholder="Pick an acquirer" class="SelectBox" name="acquirerList">
        <c:set var="acquirer" value="<%= session.getAttribute(\" acquirer\ ")%>" scope="page" />
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test='${acquirer == null}'>
                <option value="" selected="selected">All</option>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <option value="">All</option>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
        <c:forEach items="${model.acquirer}" var="acqlist">
            <c:if test='${acqlist == acquirer}'>
                <option selected="selected" value="${acqlist}">
                    <c:out value="${acqlist}" />
                </option>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test='${acqlist != acquirer}'>
                <option value="${acqlist}">
                    <c:out value="${acqlist}" />
                </option>
                <input type="checkbox" id="acquvalue" value="${acqlist}"></input>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</td>
```

somebody please help. I am trying to iterate the values in the dropdown. However, I want the tick mark symbol to be present there on selecting the values which are in the dropdown.

Comment: I can't understand how does a 'square root symbol' signifies selected options. You should probably be looking for 'check mark' symbol. See a list of all available symbols for HTML http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_dingbats.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unicode value of square root symbo which is `221A`.

Here is a pure HTML approach

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap; font-size:larger">
&radic;<span style="text-decoration:overline;">&nbsp;X&nbsp;</span>
</span>
```

The above code will give an output like this:

[image]

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rjrjrg8p/)

Comment: What is this `<string>` tag? And the `\u` notation is for JavaScript, not HTML/XML.

Comment: @Pointy:- Updated my answer. My idea was just to inform OP that he can use the unicode value of square root. I have also added the HTML approach. Thanks